# For function composition, can we take a subset of the codomain of the inner function as the domain of the outer function?

Tags: functions

Let $f:A \rightarrow B $ and $g:B \rightarrow C $ be functions. Suppose that $f $ is not surjective. I want to construct a function composition $g\circ f $. But because there is at least one $b \in B $ for every $a \in A $ such that $b\neq f (a) $, it follows that $g $ is not defined for every $b \in B $ insofar as we cannot then construct the composition

$$g \circ f : A \rightarrow C \mathrm {\, \, \, \, defined \, \,by \, \, \, \, } (g\circ f)(x)= g (f (x)) $$

However, is it permissible to take the image $f (A) \subset B $ as the domain of $g $? That is, $g: f (A) \rightarrow C $. Then we are guaranteed that every $b=f (a) \in f (A) $ is mapped by $g $ to a unique element in $C $, that is, $g\circ f $ is well-defined.

Intuitively, this makes sense, but I am not sure if it is permissible. I hope it is clear what I am asking.

Comment: "it follows that $g$ is not defined for every $b \in B$" I can't see why would that be true

Comment: To define $g \circ f$, $g$ need not be defined on all of $B$ (although the notation $g: B \to C$ says that it is, so you need to rework that!), it need only be defined on $image(f)$. Your statement "Then we are guaranteed..." is true even if $g$ is defined on all of $B$, not just on $f(A)$.

Comment: @JohnHughes Okay, so as long as $f (x)$ is in the domain of $g $, the composition is well-defined; and even if there are images $f (y) $ that are not in the domain of $g$, the very definition of composite functions ignores those elements?

Comment: Since the image of $f$ is a subset of $B$, and $B$ is the domain of $g$, there cannot be any image $f(y)$ that is not in $B$, hence there cannot be one that is not in the domain of $g$. Are you sure you expressed your question to say what you wanted?

Comment: @JohnHughes Oops I meant to say that if there are images $f (y) $ s.t. $g (f (y)) $ is undefined, does the definition of composite functions cause us to ignore those elements

Comment: If that's the case, then the domain of $g$ is not $B$. That means that your problem statement is not consistent, and you can't expect much help from us.

Comment: I'm probably not using the terminology correctly to adequately ask my question. I do have an image illustrating function composition. The middle region representing the range of $g $ was what I've been reflecting on and which prompted my question. The image $g (x) $ in the range of $g $ but outside of the domain of $f$ is, by definition, not selected by $f\circ g $. Upon looking at the image again, it seems that the functions are $f:A\rightarrow B $ and $g:C\rightarrow D $ where $B \cap C\neq \varnothing $.

Comment: Anyway, as I mentioned earlier, does the definition of composite functions cause the function to ignore those elements that make it undefined, or even outside the domain of the outermost function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g: D \to C$ is defined in a domain $D$ that contain $f(A)$ than $g \circ f : A \rightarrow C$ is well defined. So, yes, we can have $D=f(A)$.